# Visio ShapeData Modify Nested List

Tags: visio

tl;dr I'd like to allow users to modify elements of a nested variable list using ShapeData and have it reflected in the main list *without using VBA*. Is this possible?

---

## Setup

I have a semicolon-delimited list containing comma-delimited elements in a Shape's ShapeData. The list is of type `Variable List`, allowing users to add elements as they see fit. I want to also allow the sublist to be modifiable in this way. The basic setup is as follows:

| Name | Type | Format (Formula) | Format (Output) | Value (Formula) | Value (Output) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Prop.List | 4 | "1,2,3;4,6;7,8,9" | "1,2,3;4,6;7,8,9" | `=INDEX(1,Prop.List.Format`* | "4,6" |
| Prop.SubList | 4 | `=SUBSTITUTE(Prop.List,",",";")`† | "4;6" | `=INDEX(0, Prop.SubList.Format)`* | "4" |

*This formula is auto-generated when selecting an item from the dropdown in the ShapeData pane
†`SUBSTITUTE()` is necessary here in order for the dropdowns to work. Using `INDEX(0,Prop.List,",")` doesn't work

---

## Known: Modifying the List

A user can simply type values into the ShapeData field to update `Prop.List`, that's the beauty of Variable Lists. Here's what happens if a user types in `Prop.List = "10,11,12"`:

| Name | Type | Format (Formula) | Format (Output) | Value (Formula) | Value (Output) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Prop.List | 4 | "1,2,3;4,6;7,8,9;10,11,12" | "1,2,3;4,6;7,8,9;10,11,12" | `=INDEX(3,Prop.List.Format` | "10,11,12" |
| Prop.SubList | 4 | `=SUBSTITUTE(Prop.List,",",";")` | "10;11;12" | `=INDEX(0, Prop.SubList.Format)` | "10" |

This is expected! A simple and elegant solution.

---

## Unknown: Modifying the SubList

This is where I run into problems. You may have noticed that the number 5 is missing from `Prop.List`. A user probably wants to add that for the sake of completeness! Following the logic above, we first select the proper sublist from the `Prop.List` dropdown, then set `Prop.SubList = "5"`. Here's what happens:

| Name | Type | Format (Formula) | Format (Output) | Value (Formula) | Value (Output) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Prop.List | 4 | "1,2,3;4,6;7,8,9;10,11,12" | "1,2,3;4,6;7,8,9;10,11,12" | `=INDEX(1,Prop.List.Format` | "4,6" |
| Prop.SubList | 4 | "4;6;5" | "4;6;5" | `=INDEX(2, Prop.SubList.Format)` | "5" |

The value was added to the sublist, but the link between `Prop.List` and `Prop.SubList` was severed in the process. The main list doesn't include "5" and `Prop.SubList` no longer changes according to the `Prop.List` selection.

---

## Things I've Tried

*I'm going to spare you (and myself) the details of creating a table outlining the results of every attempt at a solution I've tried.*

For my actual circumstance, this list doesn't need to be sorted. "4,6,5" is perfectly valid.

### 1. Passthrough

I originally thought that the `SETATREF()` function would be my savior here. However, using various flavors of `Prop.SubList.Format = SETATREF(Prop.List)` resulted in "4;6;5" being appended to `Prop.List.Format` rather than the selected element being updated. This makes sense because anything not matching a list element gets added.

### 2. Helper Cells

A more complex solution involved using `SETF()` with multiple helper cells. Because the `Prop.SubList.Format` formula gets replaced with a string when a custom input is received, I thought of externally creating the link to enforce the formula. The first cell ensures that `Prop.SubList.Format` stays linked to `Prop.List` when the dropdown selection is changed:

`User.EnforceSubList = SETF(GETREF(Prop.SubList.Format), "=SUBSTITUTE(Prop.List,"","","";"")")) + DEPENDSON(Prop.List)`

A second cell updates the list by substituting out the old sublist with the current one

`User.UpdateList = SETF(GETREF(Prop.List.Format),SUBSTITUTE(Prop.List.Format, Prop.List, SUBSTITUTE(Prop.SubList.Format,";",",")))`

*NOTE: The above formula probably doesn't work and results in `#VALUE`. I don't know why this happens, but I'm pretty sure if you put the substitutions into a dummy cell and then reference that cell it will work!*

The logic here makes sense to me but the results quickly failed. After several selection changes, I somehow ended up with a list comprised entirely of 7s.

### 3. Un-Nesting

I can avoid nested lists altogether by just creating a unique ShapeData entry for each sublist (`Prop.SubList0` - `Prop.SubList3`) and then selectively hiding the ones I don't need.

```
User.ListIndex = LOOKUP(Prop.List,Prop.List.Format)
Prop.List.Format = SUBSTITUTE(Prop.SubList0.Format,";",",") & ";" & SUBSTITUTE(Prop.SubList1.Format...)...
Prop.SubList0.Invisible = (User.ListIndex <> 0)
...
Prop.SubList3.Invisible = (User.ListIndex <> 3)
```

This works in a hardcoded example but quickly becomes impractical as users modify `Prop.List`. I could just make an excessive amount of sublist rows, but I'd rather not.

### 4. Outsourcing

I haven't tampered much in this, but I'm aware that Visio 2016 has multiple ways of integrating with Excel to do things similar to this. I'd bet that after reading the *Actual Scenario* section, several people will be internally screaming wondering why I'm not using Excel in the first place! The simple answer is: I don't want to. Requiring users to juggle 2 programs for functionality seems unreasonable to me when it's not important for any other parts of the diagram.

### 5. VBA

This is a pretty trivial task using VBA. Unfortunately, I can't due to company restrictions.

---

## The Actual Scenario

In case you're wondering about what I'm *actually* making with this, and why I can't just manually add 5 to my list, it's an inventory of serialized items.

```
Prop.Items.Format = "Hammer;Wrench;Screwdriver;..."
User.ItemsIndex = LOOKUP(Prop.Items,Prop.Items.Format)

User.Serials = "548935,409234,324957,...;028412,111111,76843,...;..."
Prop.Serials.Format = SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(User.ItemsIndex,User.Serials),",",";")
```

I'd like users to be able to quickly add new tools when they arrive without having to dig through incredibly messy ShapeSheet cells.

---

## Bonus Question

Is there a better way capture the index of a list item without using `LOOKUP()`? It's incredibly inelegant and inefficient (`LOOKUP(INDEX(0, List),List) = 0`...duh!). I thought maybe I could set `Prop.Value = INDEX(SETATREF(User.Index), Prop.Value.Format)` but unfortunately that captures the entire function evaluation, not just the index value.

---

## Disclaimer

I don't have Visio on my home computer. All of the formulae here are off the top of my head, and likely contain some errors. The methodology has been tested and works how I've expressed, so cut me some slack and focus on the concept please.